# how to use passport in express(typescript)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

i have router and in this i call my passport

```
    route.get(
    "/signup",
  passport.authenticate("signup", { session: false }),
  (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(req);
    console.log("signup in admin routes");
    res.send("admin routes");
  }
);
```

and i call my passport in there file like this

```
const local = () => {


 passport.use(
"signup",
 new LocalStrategy(
  { usernameField: "username", passwordField: "password" },
  async (username, password, done) => {
    const result = await User.create({ username, password });
    console.log(result);
    return done(null, result);
  }
)
);
};
 export default local;
```

and when i call my router (postman) i have an error

Error: Unknown authentication strategy "signup"

```
at attempt (/run/media/afshin/New 
Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:193:39)
at authenticate (/run/media/afshin/New 
Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:370:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/run/media/afshin/New 
Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/run/media/afshin/New 
Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/run/media/afshin/New Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/run/media/afshin/New Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /run/media/afshin/New Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/run/media/afshin/New Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/run/media/afshin/New Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/run/media/afshin/New Volume/final_kian_sarma/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
```

please help what am i doning Tnks